# Sencha skeleton app has no Router

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am very new to Sencha, started today. I have a simple app based on a skeleton app I created using the 'sencha generate app' command.

All was working fine until I added a Controller for logging in. When deploying and running the app I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getRouter' Controller.js:476
Ext.define.applyRoutes Controller.js:476
setter sencha-touch.js:5441
Base.implement.initConfig sencha-touch.js:4882
Ext.define.constructor Controller.js:386
Class sencha-touch.js:5170
(anonymous function)
Ext.ClassManager.instantiate sencha-touch.js:6749
Ext.ClassManager.instantiateByAlias sencha-touch.js:6661
Ext.apply.factory sencha-touch.js:9779
Ext.define.factoryItem Container.js:609
Ext.define.add Container.js:682
Base.implement.callOverridden sencha-touch.js:4734
etc......
```

When I trace this error it seems the App needs a Router object, but it hasn't got it. I could not find anywhere how to configure a Router (it also seems to me there should be one by default).

```
applyRoutes: function(routes) {
    var app    = this instanceof Ext.app.Application ? this : this.getApplication(),
        router = app.getRouter(), // THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS
```

I have specified the controller in the App.js

```
views : ['Main', 'Home', 'Contact', 'Login', 'CreateAccount'],
controllers : ['LoginController'],
```

This is the controller:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.controller.LoginController", {
extend : "Ext.app.Controller",

xtype : 'logincontroller',

config : {
    refs : {
        loginForm : "#loginFormPanel"
    },
    control : {
        'button[action=login]' : {
            tap : "authenticateUser"
        }
    },
    views : ['Login']
},

authenticateUser : function(button) {

    this.getLoginForm().submit({
        url : 'php/process_login.php',
        method : 'POST',
        success : function(form, result) { debugger;
            var jsonoutput = Ext.decode(result);
            // json parsing
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error', "Success");

        },
        failure : function(form, result) {//This block of code is not executing even after JSON response
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error', "Invalid username/password");
        }
    });
}
```

});

The login form

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Login', {
extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',
id : 'loginFormPanel',
xtype : 'loginform',

requires : ['Ext.form.FieldSet', 'Ext.field.Password'],

config : {
    title : 'Login',
    iconCls : 'login',
    items : [{
        xtype : 'fieldset',
        title : 'Logingegevens',
        items : [{
            xtype : 'textfield',
            name : 'username',
            label : 'Gebruikersnaam'
        }, {
            xtype : 'passwordfield',
            name : 'password',
            label : 'Wachtwoord'
        }]
    }, {
        xtype : 'button',
        text : 'Login',
        id : 'loginButton',
        ui : 'action',
        action : 'login'
    }]
}
```

});

Thanks for your help, 
Coen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not specifying any routes in your Controller's config. Take a look at Sencha's [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-routes) on routing.

```
...
config: {
    routes: {
        ...
    },

    refs: {
        ...
     }
},
...
```

Comment: thanks, I had added some routes in the beginning but that seemed to not work either, now it works :)